# How to refresh (Post back) aspx page once the popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

My main page is orders.aspx from which I am opening another aspx page (Orderitems.aspx). Orderitems.aspx page opens as a popup. 
Whenever the user close the popup window the main page (Orders.aspx) should post back to load the newly added items.

My question is, How to catch the window close event and how to fire page load in that?

I use the below code to open the popup window.

```
protected void AddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "Orderitems.aspx";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin('" + url + "')</script>");
}
```

Comment: Why open it in another window? That's pretty 1990's. Why not use a modal popup? And why not use AJAX to refresh the newly loaded items?

Comment: Appreciate your comment. You mean here the AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender ?

Comment: Yeah, that's one option. Or there's [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Or [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Or whatever CSS framework you're using probably has one. And if you're not using a CSS framework, pick one! Bootstrap is pretty popular, and has been bundled with the ASP.NET Web projects for years.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Within your pop up, you can have a post back button which can be tied to a function that can redirect to page_load; you can have a counter variable to keep a track of what to load under (!isPostBack). Something like

```
<asp:Button ID="Post" Text="post" Visible="true" onclick="postBackToMain" runat="server" Width="413px" />
```

in code behind

```
protected void postBackToMain(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Response.Redirect("/Orders.aspx");
        }
```

should work.